# Which fare rules apply for the return flight?

Tags: tickets, airlines

I need to know what rules should i follow this is the scenario

Passenger already took the departure last January 05 , and his return is February 20 . He called to change the ticket to FEB 11.

Here's the FARE RULES

CHANGES

```
BEFORE DEPARTURE
  PER DIRECTION CHARGE USD 150.00 FOR REISSUE/
    REVALIDATION.
     NOTE -
      UPGRADE TO HIGHER FARE MUST BE TO THE HIGHER
      AVAILABLE CLASS IN THE FLIGHT DATE DISPLAY.

AFTER DEPARTURE
  CHANGES NOT PERMITTED.
```

*** GENERAL RULE FOLLOWS ***
BETWEEN THE UNITED STATES AND MIDDLE EAST FOR QA0RAAMP TYPE
FARES

Do I need to follow the rules of *after* departure since passenger was able to take the Departure or I need to follow again the before departure?

Comment: Could you edit the question and write a title more specific to your question? It's hard to tell this question apart from other questions the way it's written right now.

Answer (score 1):

`DEPARTURE` refers to the *first* flight, meaning your friend's flight on January 5th.  He is now `AFTER DEPARTURE` and those conditions apply, meaning he is not allowed to make any changes any more.

That said, in my experience airlines are often more flexible than the fare conditions require them to, particularly when there is money to be made in the form of change fees.  So I would encourage your friend to call them and ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot lambshaanxy , we'll just verify it as well with airline :)

Comment: Please do report back, and accept the answer (check green tick) if this worked for you.